# d3 V4.2.1 TypeScript 2.0 error importing d3-selection-multi

Tags: d3.js, typescript, systemjs, jspm

I am trying to import d3 v4 into a typescript project using jspm and systemjs. I can get d3 imported correctly using this

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

This works and it allows me to make selections etc. I tried using the attr function and passing it an object which did not work. I found that d3 v4 includes that as a separate module.

After downloading that module d3-selection-multi with jspm. I try to import it into my project like so.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import 'jspm_packages/npm/d3-selection-multi@1.0.0';
```

I then try and use the attrs function but the console logs the following error

> (index):40 Error: (SystemJS)
>   d3.selectAll(...).data(...).style(...).attrs is not a function(…)

I am also getting some compile error which i get all the time but yet they always still compile and the code runs

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'd3'
error TS1110: Type expected
```

Can any one explain what I am doing wrong and offer a solution?

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but if that `style` also uses an object, it has to be `styles`.

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado Yes but how to I get them to work without throwing an error

Comment: First, check if selection-multi us being loaded. Create a simple code, something like `var test = d3.select("foo").attrs({"bar":"baz});` and see if it works.

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado it does not work. I get the following error: d3.select(...).attrs is not a function

Comment: Yep, so you probably have a problem importing selection-multi. Let's wait and see if someone comes to help you. Meanwhile, as a workaround, remember that you can always use several `attr` chained.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
  import * as d3 from 'd3';
  import 'd3-selection-multi';
```

Comment: angular-cli complains about this. `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_d3__.select(...).attrs is not a function` :-(

Comment: @ØysteinAmundsen Did you ever figure this issue out? I'm experiencing the exact same confusing problem.

Comment: @Cowman I posted my solution as an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842984/d3-v4-2-1-typescript-2-0-error-importing-d3-selection-multi/41032977#41032977

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to create a 'bundle' file and import that instead of importing individual d3 packages. This is probably not ideal, but it works (I've commented out packages which I do not need, in order to save on space):

```
// export * from 'd3-array';
// export * from 'd3-axis';
// export * from 'd3-brush';
// export * from 'd3-chord';
// export * from 'd3-collection';
// export * from 'd3-color';
// export * from 'd3-dispatch';
// export * from 'd3-drag';
// export * from 'd3-dsv';
// export * from 'd3-ease';
// export * from 'd3-force';
// export * from 'd3-format';
// export * from 'd3-geo';
// export * from 'd3-hierarchy';
// export * from 'd3-interpolate';
// export * from 'd3-path';
// export * from 'd3-polygon';
// export * from 'd3-quadtree';
// export * from 'd3-queue';
// export * from 'd3-random';
// export * from 'd3-request';
// export * from 'd3-scale';
export * from 'd3-selection';
export * from 'd3-selection-multi';
export * from 'd3-shape';
// export * from 'd3-time';
// export * from 'd3-time-format';
// export * from 'd3-timer';
// export * from 'd3-transition';
// export * from 'd3-voronoi';
// export * from 'd3-zoom';
```

To use this, I just have to:

```
import * as D3 from './d3.bunde.ts';
```

P.S. Probably doesn't matter, but I'm building my project using angular-cli.

Comment: This is useful for me! In addition I added them to my vendors entry in my webpack config so it doesn't put the d3 code towards my app entry.

Answer (score 0):

Working "`jspm` + `d3-selection-multi`" example: https://github.com/jakeNiemiec/jspm_d3

If you need to import all of D3, use `jspm install npm:d3`. This will add quite a bit of bloat. Remember that jspm comes with rollup, [take a look at the build script in package.json](https://github.com/jakeNiemiec/jspm_d3/blob/master/package.json#L9).